# Waking my MacBook Pro for a backup at night

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, backup, sleep, time-machine

I have FileVault turned on, which means that Time Machine won't back up my data while I'm logged in. Is there any way to get my MacBook to wake once at night, say 6 AM, to start a Time Machine backup and then go back to sleep when done? This way I can log out at night when I'm done with it and it can back up my home folder's sparsebundle file.

Comment: Oops, forgot about apple.stackexchange. Can someone move this there?

Comment: You're not off-topic here. I'd suggest you wait a day or two, and, if nobody answers, then flag for moderator attention.

Comment: When FileVault is activated, your home directory is automatically backed up upon log out (after compacting of the FileVault sparsebundle disk image) if the backup disk is connected. There's absolutely no need for you to wake your Mac. Just log out, and make sure your Mac goes to sleep afterwards with appropriate power settings.

Comment: It won't wake up for a backup though right? Are there settings that will allow Time Machine to wake it for a backup?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Backup upon logout, and you're good. Since it's *absolutely unnecessary*, there's no such feature, AFAIK.

Comment: How do I trigger a backup upon logout *and* ensure that the backup completes before I close the lid? AFAIK, there's no Time Machine interface at the login window and when I just shut the lid during a backup, the backup failed. I suppose I should add, I don't like leaving the lid of my MBP open.

Comment: Simple: Don't close the lid. Let your power settings turn off the machine once backup's done. This could be dangerous otherwise: I wouldn't want to power up the machine with the lid closed; it might power up or be running while in a nice comfy laptop bag and overheat.

Comment: This is true. However I don't like the laptop going to sleep by itself, I prefer to have it only go to sleep when I tell it to (usually by closing the lid).

Comment: So you'd prefer it waking up and going to sleep on its own to only going to sleep on its own? // I'm quite certain there's no reasonable way to do this (we're talking about backups after all — I actually like seeing it start to work on that, since I know that way that it's actually working!); so I wish you good luck with your question.

Comment: Yes, I would. Microsoft has this figured out pretty well, as all my Windows desktops and laptops automatically wake themselves in sequence at night, perform a backup and then go back to sleep. I just want to add my MacBook Pro in there while still maintaining the security of FileVault if I take it out of the house and should lose it.

Comment: This user found the command to cause TM to start a backup: http://bit.ly/ihSLg7 and if I turn off automatic TM backups, it would then duplicate the behavior of my WHS machines (which is basically what I'm after). I can use Energy Saver to wake the machine 1 minute right before I want the action to happen and I think I can use cron to execute that command on a schedule, right? The only question is if this will sleep from the same script: http://bit.ly/aSWYHG

Comment: I discovered a new problem with just letting it do it all by itself. There seems to be a bug with Time Machine and SMB shares such that when it goes to remount the network share and for whatever reason can't, Finder freezes (and eventually everything else too). I can't even reboot the system normally. Will have to try the suggestions in Jon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT Whoops! Didn't read that you had to be logged out... well, I'll just leave this here, hopefully a starting point.

Not sure if this is what you want but try it and let me know:

Use Terminal to wake Mac at scheduled time:

`pmset schedule wake "12/26/2009 00:00:00"`

Set date as preferred. Exchange wake for sleep to put Mac to sleep at scheduled time.

UPDATE: I knew there was a way to do this with Automator: http://masonsklut.com/blog/customize-time-machine-backup-times/